# Ошибка invalid syntax в строке с emojy

Tags: python

Я пишу бота на python, который выдает роли по кнопке с эмоджи. Сначала с единственной строкой во вкладке с ролями все было хорошо. Когда добавил вторую строку, то начало выдавать ошибку.

```
    ROLES = {
        '⭐': 812724061138452491  # роль, с которой все было хорошо
        '': 812724143664791562  # роль, с которой все сломалось
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропустили запятую:

```py
ROLES = {
    '⭐': 812724061138452491,  # <--
    '': 812724143664791562
}
```

*P.S.: Советую ставить также завершающие запятые.*

Comment: Спасибо, и правда, пропустил